# Rn sound issue:play in background but stop music on phone call

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-sound

I am building an app using react native sound. Everything works fine.background music is playing well but it also plays while phone  call is in progress. When phone ringing music  stops but  resumes as soon as call is received.
     Also I am using app state to control music in active and background.
       Does anyone has idea how can I pause  music when phone rings or call is in progress and resume when call is disconnected.

```
componentDidMount() {
AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  this.stop()
   }

   _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
   if (nextAppState === 'active') {
   console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
   } else if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
    console.log('App has come to the inactive!');
     this.stop()
     }
   else {
   }
   this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
```

also inactive appstate does not occur in android.
if i disable background audio using appstate it stops audio for 
1.app background state.
2.phone lock state.
3.in phone call incoming outgoing state.
and vise versa
i want audio to play in phone lock state screen light turned off.
but at same time do not play in background state.

Comment: show some code of your app's logic.

Comment: i have added code for which i want solution plz check.thanks    my main aim is to stop playing audio during call incoming and outgoing.if you have any better solution plz suggest . i am using react native sound

Comment: @KRISHNAYADAV Did you manage to get it to work?